# Why won't Maven exclude test dependency even when in exclusion?

Tags: maven, junit, maven-enforcer-plugin

I have the following...

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.stefanbirkner</groupId>
        <artifactId>system-rules</artifactId>
        <version>[1.19.0,)</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

But when I run `mvn clean package` I get...

```
Dependency convergence error for junit:junit:4.11 paths to dependency are:
+-my.pkg:project:0.0.3-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.github.stefanbirkner:system-rules:1.19.0
    +-junit:junit:4.11
and
+-my.pkg:project:0.0.3-SNAPSHOT
  +-junit:junit:4.13.2
```

Why is it not ignoring the dep?

Comment: I agree with the "use dependency management" answer. As to why the above did not work, did you run `mvn dependency:tree` to examine the transitive dependencies? Maybe you need to also exclude junit-dep.

Comment: @Barchetta Already did that the enforcer plugin says specifically where it is coming from. Other transitive dependencies didn't have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real way to "repair" a dependency convergence error is to use `<dependencyManagement>`.

Put the entry

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.13.2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

into the POM. This will set the version for all transitive dependencies. Not exclusions needed anymore.

Comment: Thanks I will try it this way